# Where is the real fault in my Noverov Alogorithm + Schroedinger Equation?[Physics]

Tags: python, physics

I am solving Schroedinger Equation with help of the Noverov Theorom. So, My initial project question is: Solve s-wave Schroedinger Equation for the ground state and first excited state of the hydrogen atom:

D^2y+2(E-V(r))y=0 , D=d/dr

and potential is    V(r)=-1/r

But I want to make the program a program which automatically calculate it's eigen energies and using hatree units and reconsidering it: here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dom=[0.001,5]
n=10
r,dr=np.linspace(dom[0],dom[1],n,retstep=True)
def Potential(x,E):
    energy=2*(E+(1/x))
    return energy
i=0
E=-2
s0i=0.0
s1i=0.0001
si=np.zeros(n)
indi=0
while i==0:
    si[0]=s0i
    si[1]=s1i
    for j in range(0,n-2,1):
        f0c=((dr**2)*Potential(x=r[j],E=E))/12.0
        f1c=((dr**2)*Potential(x=r[j+1],E=E))/12.0
        f2c=((dr**2)*Potential(x=r[j+2],E=E))/12.0

        s2i=((2*(1-5*f1c)*s1i)-((1+f0c)*s0i))/(1+f2c)
        s1i=s2i
        s0i=s1i
        si[j+2]=s2i
    if abs(s2i)<=1e-18:
        i=1
    elif s2i>1e-18:
        E=E-0.1
    elif s2i<-1e-18:
        E=E+0.1
    elif(indi==500):
        i=1

    print('loop Count : ',indi,'Energy : ',E,'last Pshi',si[-1])
    indi+=1
    
print(len(r),len(si))
plt.plot(r,si)
plt.show()
```

I didn't understand where is the issue and I got some hilarious result. So Please help me to do so .

Answer (score 0):

I see you speak dutch. So I hope it is good that I answer in my native language.

Je weet dat er een [sympy module](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/hydrogen.html) is waarmee je het ook kan oplossen? Het is al geschreven code die het voor je oplost.

```
from sympy.physics.hydrogen import E_nl
from sympy.abc import n, Z

E_nl(n, Z)    # output: -Z**2/(2*n**2)
              # Z = atoomnummer       n = het quantum getal
              # Z=1 (hydrogen) bij default kan je veranderen trouwens
E_nl(1)       # output: -1/2

E_nl(2)       # output: -1/8

E_nl(3)       # output: -1/18

E_nl(3, 47)   # output: -2209/18
```

Maar uiteraard is het ook interessant om je eigen code te schrijven.
In je code ontstaat er een overflow
aangezien het deze errror geeft:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

en als je kijkt naar de antwoorden is dat niet heel raar.

```
loop Count :  78 Energy :  -2.1 last Pshi 1.9967193884115876e+306
loop Count :  79 Energy :  -2.1 last Pshi NaN
```

dat betekent dus een 1 met 306 nullen er achter.... erg groot getal, en het wijkt steeds verder van van de verwachte -1/2. Dus ergens loopt ie verkeerd door jouw berekening heen. Zou je de berekening duidelijker kunnen uitschrijven?